# How do I break out of the loop at anytime with a keypress while in another window?

Tags: python, macros

Hey I'm a beginner programmer, trying to write some code to press the letter 'k' on the keyboard every 4 seconds, while also being able to shut down the program with a keystroke WHILE IN A DIFFERENT WINDOW.

I've tried using this,

```
import time
import pyautogui

def kicker():
    while True:
        time.sleep(4)
        pyautogui.press('k')

try:
    while True:
        kicker()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

but I can only KeyboardInterrupt while the window I am coding in (jupyter notebook) is open, when I go into another window (with jupyter still open in the background) I can no longer interrupt the loop.

How can I make it so I can interrupt the loop on a keypress (not necessarily KeyboardInterrupt) while not on the jupyter notebook window?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [pyxhook](https://github.com/JeffHoogland/pyxhook) to listen for all keystrokes on your machine. Do note that this is roughly the same as a keylogger and might involve admin access on your machine so there may be some safety concerns to think about.

Here is an example [script](https://github.com/JeffHoogland/pyxhook/blob/master/example.py) from the repo that showcases it printing the event, but the line of interest is the function on line 15:

```py
def kbevent(event):
    global running

    if event.Ascii == <...Put ascii code for k here...>:
        running = False
```